# Makefile - Issue with referencing parent directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile from a sample project that tries to reference the parent directory as "../bin". This does not seem to work when running "make install". The error I get is:

```
cp: cannot stat `/bin/build/*': No such file or directory
```

The layout of the project is:

**/bin**

**/src/makefile**

(So when I run the makefile, the current directory is /src/)

It appears referencing the parent directory with ".." is incorrect. I know I can reference the current directory with {$CURDIR} variable, but I need to know the proper variable or way to reference the parent directory so /bin/ is referenced correctly. I think I might be able to work around this by moving the makefile, but I want to know the real way to do this for future use.

The makefile looks like this (problem ares highlighted with ##### problem ######)

```
# The name of the extension.
extension_name := xulschoolhello

# The UUID of the extension.
extension_uuid := helloworld@xulschool.com

# The name of the profile dir where the extension can be installed.
profile_dir := 8mtbjosv.development

# The zip application to be used.
ZIP := zip

# The target location of the build and build files.
bin_dir := ../bin ##### problem ######

# The target XPI file.
xpi_file := $(bin_dir)/$(extension_name)2.xpi

# The type of operating system this make command is running on.
os_type := $(patsubst darwin%,darwin,$(shell echo $(OSTYPE)))

# The location of the extension profile.
ifeq ($(os_type), darwin)
  profile_location := \
    ~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/$(profile_dir)/extensions/\{$(extension_uuid)\}
else
  ifeq ($(os_type), linux-gnu)
    profile_location := \
      ~/.mozilla/firefox/$(profile_dir)/extensions/
  else
    profile_location := \
      "$(subst \,\\,$(APPDATA))\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\$(profile_dir)\\extensions\\{$(extension_uuid)}"
  endif
endif

# The temporary location where the extension tree will be copied and built.
build_dir := $(bin_dir)/build ##### problem ######

# This builds the extension XPI file.
.PHONY: all
all: $(xpi_file)
    @echo
    @echo "Build finished successfully."
    @echo

# This cleans all temporary files and directories created by 'make'.
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf $(build_dir)
    @rm -f $(xpi_file)
    @echo "Cleanup is done."

# The sources for the XPI file.
xpi_built := install.rdf \
             chrome.manifest \
             $(wildcard content/*.js) \
             $(wildcard content/*.xul) \
             $(wildcard content/*.xml) \
             $(wildcard content/*.css) \
             $(wildcard skin/*.css) \
             $(wildcard skin/*.png) \
             $(wildcard locale/*/*.dtd) \
             $(wildcard locale/*/*.properties)

$(build_dir) $(xpi_built): $(xpi_built)

# This builds everything except for the actual XPI, and then it copies it to the
# specified profile directory, allowing a quick update that requires no install.
.PHONY: install
install: $(build_dir) $(xpi_built)
    @echo "Installing in profile folder: $(profile_location)"
    @cp -Rf $(build_dir)/* $(profile_location)     ##### problem ######
    @echo "Installing in profile folder. Done!"
    @echo


$(xpi_file): $(xpi_built)
    @echo "Creating XPI file."
    @$(ZIP) $(xpi_file) $(xpi_built)
    @echo "Creating XPI file. Done!"
```

I am using GNU Make 3.81 on Linux Mint 12.

Thanks.

Output of

```
@echo "Installing in profile folder: $(profile_location)"
    @echo ${build_dir}
    @echo ${profile_location}
```

is :

```
Installing in profile folder: ~/.mozilla/firefox/8mtbjosv.development/extensions/
../bin/build
/home/owner/.mozilla/firefox/8mtbjosv.development/extensions/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to check that the destination folder, `$(profile_location)`, exists and that it is writable. Also, make sure that the line endings have the proper Linux format (\n). I'm not able to spot any other error at the moment.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the issue. I chmod'd $(profile_location) and still get the same error. Line endings are fine too.

Comment: That's just plain weird... Could you do an echo on `$(build_dir)` and `$(profile_location)` instead of the cp? Also, have you typed the error here or have you copied it from the terminal? There is a small inconsistency in the quotes, if you look carefully... Maybe this is a clue.

Comment: The output is straight from terminal - and I agree it looks odd but not sure what could cause that. I have appended the output you requested to the end of the question.

Comment: I just noticed that I have an error message from chmod (unrelated to this issue) that has the same quote format, so I think this is just terminal being weird: "Try `chmod --help' for more information."

Comment: Maybe the "*" doesn't match what it should. Could you try to target a specific file instead? Just as a test...

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want but - I tried "@cp -Rf $(build_dir)/xulschoolhello2.xpi $(profile_location)", which is the only file there, and I get "cp: cannot stat `../bin/build/xulschoolhello2.xpi': No such file or directory"

Comment: OK, I guess now we ruled out any trivial explanation, except one: have you used cd to navigate to the src directory before running the make install command? :) If this is not the issue, then I will let someone with more expertise have a shot at this...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10672/discussion-between-bryan-and-mihai-todor)

Answer (score 0):

What if it is running so that ../bin is relative to where the makefile is, but not where it is running? If make clean works, then it's a sign that might be the case. Look for some compiler options to give verbose output, then put a "pwd" statement there to see how it resolves.

Comment: Both the makefile and where I am running from are the same (the src directory). Issuing a "pwd" right before the "cp" command correctly shows that the current directory is project/src.

Comment: Maybe with the /* on the build_dir to the cp command doesn't contain any directories-the -R on the cp command is for recursive, I'm sure it will work if you put just build_dir there instead

Comment: I tried removing the recursive option as well as getting rid of "/*" but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but when trying to reference the parent directory in a command using GNU Make 4.2.1 I found that I had to escape the forward slash...

```
backup:
    @tar -czvpf ..\/$(PROGRAM)-`date +'%Y%m%d%H%M'`.tar.gz $(FILES)
```